# AngularJS post queries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I need form data to be unchangeable after pushed. It's now changing when in writes something in inputs.

```
var formData = {
    id: 1,
    example: "default",
    email: "default",
    name: "default",
    phone: "default",
};
formData = $scope.contact.data;
console.log("posting data....");
console.log(formData);
$rootScope.contacts.push(formData);
```

Comment: Maybe just disable the fields? Or hold the **real** data in seperate variables.

Comment: can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: Please read [ask] and give a properly detailed explanation of what you are doing and what is happening differently than expected behavior. Your description is not detailed enough for a proper answer

Comment: Edit the question and also provide more code context

Comment: Why have you tagged angular2 when this is for angularjs?

Comment: Sorry im learning this community , new here. Will do next time.

Answer (score -1):

You have to copy the object instead of assigning it, since its uses reference. 
you can use angular.extend;

```
var formData = angular.extend({}, $scope.contact.data);
$rootScope.contacts.push(formData);
```